# Assign struct C++ with HLSL variable

Tags: c++, struct, hlsl, assign, directx-10

I've only start working with DirectX, so I've get this problem:

I'm trying to push/send/assign a c++ struct in/into/with HLSL variable which have the same datatype with a struct from C++.

In C++:

```
struct Light 
{
    Light() {
        ZeroMemory(this, sizeof(Light));
    }
    D3DXVECTOR3 LightPos;
    float ID;
};
Light L1;

/.../

ID3D10EffectVariable* L1Var = NULL;

/.../

L1Var = Effect->GetVariableByName("L1")->AsVector();

/.../


L1Var->SetRawValue(&L1, 0, sizeof(Light));
```

HLSL code:

```
struct Light {
    float3 LightPos;
    float ID;
};

Light L1;
```

I'm trying to sent struct from C++ to 'L1' in HLSL, but I'm not sure with correctness of L1 type in HLSL.
This code is working but I've also get a 0 for whole parameters in L1... I don't know how to fix this, I google it for 5 hours with no result... pls help.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First if you are new to DirectX programming, I'd suggest *not* investing in DirectX 10. You should use DirectX 11 as it's far better supported, has a lot more relevant utility code, and is supported on every platform that supports DirectX 10. Furthermore, you are using legacy D3DX math, so again you should definitely move to a more modern development environment. There's very few reasons to use the legacy DirectX SDK today. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) for the background here. You will find [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and it's [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) a good starting point. If you really want to stick with the Effect system, see [Effects 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11).

Keep in mind that HLSL Constant Buffers use packing and alignment in subtly different ways than standard C/C++ structures. You get more intuitive behavior if you stick with 4-vector structures where possible instead of using 3-vector versions. In theory your C/C++ and HLSL structures are a 'match' packing the data into a single 4-vector, but various compiler settings and packing rules might throw that off. See [Packing Rules for Constant Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509632.aspx). A good way to verify that is to use `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(sizeof(L1) == 16, "CB/struct mismatch");
```

The problem is most likely your usage of the effect system. `L1Var` is probably a dummy variable due to a failed lookup, so your `SetRawValue` isn't going to do anything. From the snippet of HLSL you've provided, it's not clear to me that your `L1` HLSL variable is even a constant buffer. Try some debug code:

```
auto tempVar = Effect->GetVariableByName("L1");
if ( tempVar->IsValid() )
{
    D3DX10_EFFECT_VARIABLE_DESC desc={0};
    tempVar->GetDesc(desc);
    OutputDebugStringA(desc.Name); // Set a breakpoint here and look at desc
    OutputDebugStringA("\n");
}
else
{
    OutputDebugStringA("L1 is not valid!\n");
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Would like too help with one more thing? :  can help me to pass 2D array of float3 from c++ to hlsl?

Comment: You can't pass arbitrary length blocks of data to the shader. You must pick the maximum size and always send that much.  See the shader for [SkinnedEffect](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/Shaders/SkinnedEffect.fx) for an example (see the ``Bones`` array). Make sure your overall constant buffer size is supported by your target [Direct3D hardware feature level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx).